# How to `git pull` from the original branch

Tags: git, github

I'm not very familiar with `git` and just use the common commands. I forked a repository from `github.com` to my own account, and checked it into my local machine and create a new branch to make some development, thus my modifications are pushed into the new branch, the original `master` is still in the version when I forked. But, the original repository is still  alive and updated frequently, now I want to update my forked repository with the updates in the original repository, how could I do to avoid the inflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two general choices: Rebase or Merge.

### Rebase

Rebasing takes the committed changes you have made and rewrites them as if they had been written against the *newest* revision of the master branch. To do this, make sure your work is committed on your branch and then:

```
git checkout master
git pull --ff-only
git checkout your-branch
git rebase master
```

You may get merge conflicts which you will have to resolve. See the documentation for details.

### Merge

Merging takes the two histories (the master history and your work) and merges them together. To do this, make sure your work is committed on your branch and then:

```
git checkout master
git pull --ff-only
git checkout your-branch
git merge master
```

You may get merge conflicts which you will have to resolve. See the documentation for details.

The choice of whether to do a rebase or a merge is largely one of preference. If you have changes that you have not shared with anybody else, then a rebase is often appropriate because it keeps your history more linear. However, if you have shared your changes with anybody else, then you definitely want to do a merge because that does not modify the commits that have already been made.